# How can I download this hotfix from Microsoft?

Tags: windows, hotfix

This is the hotfix I'm after: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981214

They say that they will send me an email with the password, but the email they send doesn't actually include a password! (but otherwise looks the same as their example).

Can I get this hotfix some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out how to do this.

Apparently the hotfix website was written by someone who, erm, didn't quite know what they were doing. [More details here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/i-need-the-username-and-password-to-download-a/2baf91e4-38af-42d9-a9d0-e54eacee54c1?tab=MoreHelp).

The fix is to open the link **in Internet Explorer**, and open it **in several tabs**. One of them will work, eventually. This advice is still applicable.